# Update MongoDB subdocument using PHP code

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to create mongoDB subdocuments record inside PHP code,

```
{
    "_id": "",
    "ref": [
        {
          "crm_base_contact_id": "1653",
          "crm_imported_files_id": "906"
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "First_name": "Annalee",
            "Last_name": "Graleski",
        },
        {
            "First_name": "Henry",
            "Last_name": "Smith",
        }
    ],
}
```

How to create two arrays inside "data" subdocuments in php code .
Please provide me any idea to insert this in mongoDB using PHP code,

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to create a document like what you are displaying, or trying to add **extra** elements to your `data` field in the document.

Comment: @NeilLunn I want to add one more sub document "history" to this document using update statement in php code

Comment: Still not very clear. Do you want one more item "history" at the top level, ie ( _id, ref, data, history ) or do you want to add "history" to the items in data ie each item ( First_Name, Last_Name, history )

Comment: , ie ( _id, ref, data, history ) like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional fields with the $set operator when updating a document:

```js
db.collection.update({},{"$set": { "history": "value" }})
```

If you want that field to be an array or sub-document then it is just the same:

```js
db.collection.update({},{"$set": { "history": ["a","b","c"] }})
```

If you are struggling with converting the JSON syntax into php code, then here is something that will help you in the future:

```php
$result = '{"$set": { "history": ["a","b","c"] }}';
echo var_dump( json_decode( $result ) );
$test = array( '$set' => array('history' => array( 'a', 'b', 'c') ) );

echo json_encode( $test ) ."\n"
```

So the first line just decodes the json and will dump what it should look like. If you are not sure, then json_encode your php array declaration to see that you have it right.